# What using do I need to reference Uno.Web.Http.CookieManager

Tags: webassembly, uno-platform

Roughly following uno-prism template.
Can't find `Uno.Web.Http.CookieManager`. Actually can't find `Uno.Web`.
What am I missing?

Tried:

```
using Uno;
using Uno.UI;
using Uno.UI.Toolkit;
using Uno.UI.Web;
using Windows.Web.Http;
```

It doesn't like: `using Uno.Web`;

NuGet installed:

```
Uno.Core
Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp
Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls
Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid
Uno.UI
Uno.UI.RemoteControl
Uno.UI.WebAssembly
Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap
Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.DevServer
```

## Here is the class

- it should just pass through under UWP.
- Issue is Uno.Web.Http has red squiggles under "Web" and won't compile under WASM.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Prism.Mvvm;


namespace LogManPrism.Model
{
    public class CookieMonster : BindableBase
    {
        private void SetCookie(string key, string value)
        {
#if __WASM__
            var cookie  = new Uno.Web.Http.Cookie(key, value);
            var request = new Uno.Web.Http.SetCookieRequest(cookie)
            {
                Path = "/",
                Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(12),
                Secure = true,
            };
            Uno.Web.Http.CookieManager.GetDefault().SetCookie(request);
#endif
        }

        private string GetCookie(string key)
        {
#if __WASM__
            var cookie = Uno.Web.Http.CookieManager.GetDefault().FindCookie(key);

            return cookie != null ? cookie.Value : string.Empty;
#else
            return string.Empty;
#endif  
        }

        private void DeleteCookie(string key)
        {
#if __WASM__
            Uno.Web.Http.CookieManager.GetDefault().DeleteCookie(key, path: "/");
#endif
        }



        public void SetThisBeast(string s)
        {
            SetCookie("A", s);
        }

        public string GetItBack()
        {
            string s = GetCookie("A");

            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? "no beast here" : s;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to use:

```
using Uno.Web.Http;
```

You can see the source [here](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/master/src/Uno.UWP/Web/Http/CookieManager.wasm.cs). Also note that this class is only available on WebAssembly, so the usage of it needs to be either in a target-specific library or wrapped in `#if __WASM__` (see [here](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/features/working-with-cookies.html) for example).

Comment: Still can't figure it out.

Comment: I just edited original question to include actual class - looked at source, understand CookieManager is static, using `#if __WASM__`, Thanks for "FindCookie".

Comment: I must be missing a NuGet or something really basic

Comment: The fix for this issue was just merged, sorry for the inconvenience https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/6723. Now the changes will be built in master and the next released NuGet preview packages will contain this.